# Create facebook share button while concatenating

Tags: jquery, facebook

Im trying to create facebook share buttons like this

```
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank">
    </a>
```

But I need the url to dynamically change depending on the page.

This jQuery does not work. Just leaves the href on the element blank

```
 <a href="" id="facebook" class="b-social-media-shares__a b-social-media-shares--facebook" target="_blank" >
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var url      = window.location.href; 
console.log(url)
$('#facebook').attr("href",  "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + url )

});
```

Comment: Your code has an (obvious) syntax error `var facebook = ;`  Always check the console for errors.

Comment: Oh sorry was trying out some other variables and left that in when writing this Q. Updated but problem still the same

Comment: 1) do you get the console.log? 2) how are you testing that it "just leaves the href blank"?  3) Have you tried recreating it, eg in a snippet here in your question?  While it's obvious it should work, quickly converting your code to a snippet to make sure shows that, yes, it does work.   There must be something else causing it to not work.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log($("[id=facebook]").length)` (inside your doc ready, just before your code) ?

Comment: Length is 1 when console logging

Comment: Ok, then your only option is to try to recreate the issue elsewhere, eg here in a snippet.

Comment: You haven't answered how you're testing it - if you're doing "view source" then that will be as it was.  Also, if there's any other script error then it won't change it.